# Is Hidan still alive?

Tags: naruto

From what I recall, Hidan's head was buried deep inside a hole in the Konoha Forbidden Jungle.

Does it mean that Hidan is still alive after all this year? Is it possible for someone to rescue him and bring him back if he is still alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hidan)

> Though believed dead by Akatsuki, Hidan is in fact alive but is dying slowly from a lack of nutrition.
>
> When Kakuzu was reincarnated during the Fourth Shinobi World War, he took Hidan's absence as proof that he was still alive.

Comment: So we can conclude that Hidan is dead, since nobody going to rescue him, we already know that. Plus, Hidan's main advantage is his inability to die from virtually all causes, with the exception of malnutrition.

Comment: but the toll for beeing immortal is that he serves his god jashin and present him sacrifice. so since he isn't able to do this, his power of immortality shoudl vanish and he will die then

Answer (score 3):

Although it's mostly based on speculation and it isn't really mentioned in the series that that he is definitely alive, when Kakuzu was reincarnated during the Fourth Shinobi World War, [he took Hidan's absence as proof that he was still alive](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hidan#Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Confrontation) (Chapter 530, page 3).

Comment: Its not speculation.  They said he's an effective immortal and he would be buried there forever with Shikimaru's clan's forest watching over it.

Comment: @Quikstryke Please do not forget that Kakuzu specifically said there is no such thing an immortal when he talked with Shikamaru when they met (I think for the second time).

Comment: but Hidan is well and truly immortal thats why Shikamaru had to bury him alive or else a smart cookie like Shikamaru would've figured a way to kill him

Comment: @HashiramaSenju from the [link](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hidan#Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Confrontation) you provided quote  "Though believed dead by Akatsuki,[42] Hidan is in fact alive but is dying slowly from a lack of nutrition.[10]"

Comment: But take note that you need the DNA of Hidan in order to reanimate his body. His absence doesn't really mean that he is still alive. Maybe there are just no DNA sample present.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Well, if could get the DNA of the second Mizukage, i'm sure getting the data he needed about Hidan would be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

he is dead, the 4th databook states that he required nutrients to survive like anyone else. this means food and water, no human can survive longer then a week without water so he was dead within a week

Comment: I don't recall Hidan being featured in the 4th databook. Did you perhaps mean the 3th? If not, could you include a reference to the page it was mentioned perhaps.

Comment: @Dimitrimx by "3th" do you actually mean "3rd"?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, Hiran can only die from starvation, though he could have figured a way to get out of the hole at shikamaru’s forest, or someone could have found him and rescued him, idk but that would be a sick arch